# Singular value decomposition for matrices that are not square?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, matrix-decomposition

I understand that the Singular Value Decomposition is defined as SVD = $U\Sigma V^T$ , but I am slightly confused about the calculations when the matrix is not square. 
For example, I have the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-2 & 2 \\
2 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
When I am solving for $V$, however, I am missing the last component. Have I done something wrong when calculating for matrices that are not square matrices?

$$\det(A^T A - \lambda I) = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 - \lambda & -4 & 4 \\
        -4 & 8 - \lambda & -8\\
        4 & -8 & 8 - \lambda
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$\lambda = 0, 2, 16$
Eigenvectors respectively are: 
\begin{bmatrix}             
        1  \\           
        1/2 \\
        0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}             
        1  \\           
        2/7 \\
       -2/7
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}             
        0  \\           
        1 \\
       -1
 \end{bmatrix}
Therefore $$\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}             
        \sqrt 2  & 0 & 0  \\           
        0 & \sqrt 16 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}$$
Also, $$V = 
\begin{bmatrix}
       7/\sqrt 57 & 0 & 2/\sqrt 5 \\
       2/\sqrt 57 & 1/\sqrt 2 & 1/\sqrt 5 \\
       2/\sqrt 57 & -1/\sqrt 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is the portion I am confused about.
Is $U = AV / \sqrt\lambda $ ? What if I have am missing a vector so that I can only get the first two columns of $U$?

Comment: To answer the question you should describe your process of obtaining an SVD, perhaps even exemplifying with a working example.

Comment: Will do! I may need a few minutes to type everything out.

Comment: Your matrix has 3 rows and 2 columns, so just to make the dimensions match you must have $U$ with 3 rows and $V^T$ with 2 columns. Is that what you mean by the "missing last component"?

Comment: I believe so. I'm having issues with the calculations.

Comment: @Shanty I don't have time to go into detail. But $\Sigma$ must be the same size as $A$, i.e., $3\times 2$. And $U$ is going to be $3\times 3$ while $V$ is going to be $2\times 2$. You didn't actually find $\det\left(A^*A-\lambda I\right)$, you found $\det\left(AA^*-\lambda I\right)$. If there were no computational mistakes, you got your $U$.

Comment: I'm glad I'm on the right track then! Thank you!

Comment: @Shanty By the way, I didn't realise that the $*$ in your question was just multiplication, I thought it was transconjugation, so in my comment above replace $^*$ with $^T$.

Answer (score 2):

First, correct a simple error
$$
\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
 9 & -9 \\
 -9 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right].
$$

This system matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is a rank one matrix (column 2 = $-$column 1) with singular value decomposition
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} 
&= 
\mathbf{U}\, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & -1 \\
 -2 & 2 \\
 2 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
&= 
% U
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{3}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\
  2 \\
 -2
\end{array}
\right]}
&
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -2 \\
  0 \\
  1
\end{array}
\right]}
&
\frac{1}{3\sqrt{5}}
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  2 \\
  5 \\
  4
\end{array}
\right]}
%
\end{array}
\right]
% sigma
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% V
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{-1} & \color{blue}{1} \\
 \color{red}{1}   & \color{red}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right].
\end{align}
$$
Blue vectors are in range spaces, red vectors in null spaces.

The thin SVD uses the range space components only:
$$
  \mathbf{A} = 
% U
\frac{1}{3}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\
  2 \\
 -2
\end{array}
\right]}
% S
\left( 3\sqrt{2} \right)
% V
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{-1} & \color{blue}{1}
\end{array}
\right].
$$

---

You may benefit from this example: 
[SVD and the columns — I did this wrong but it seems that it still works, why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287795/svd-and-the-columns-i-did-this-wrong-but-it-seems-that-it-still-works-why/2297254#2297254)